# ereg_replace to preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, posix-ere

How can I convert

```
ereg_replace(".*\.(.*)$","\\1",$imgfile);
```

to

```
preg_replace... ?
```

?

I'm having trouble with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/.*\.(.*)$/", "\\1", "foo.jpg")
```

I don't know why PHP requires the `/` delimiters.  The only reason Perl, JS, etc. have them is that they allow regex literals, which PHP doesn't.

Comment: It is because they opt to use the single string to provide both the modifier and the regex pattern. `"/[a-z]/i"`.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php .. for example, `$a = 'string/with/slashes'; $b = preg_replace('#/with/#', '-without-', $a);` is valid, sets `$b` to `string-without-slashes` and you do not have to escape the `/` in the regex given to `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 23):

**You should know 4 main things to port ereg patterns to preg:**

1. **Add delimiters**(/): `'pattern' => '/pattern/'`
2. **Escape delimiter** if it is a part of the pattern: `'patt/ern' =>
   '/patt\/ern/'`
    
   Achieve it programmatically in following way:
   `$ereg_pattern = '<div>.+</div>';` 
   `$preg_pattern = '/' .addcslashes($ereg_pattern, '/') . '/';`
3. **eregi**(case-insensitive matching): `'pattern' => '/pattern/i'` So, if
   you are using eregi function for case insenstive matching, just add
   'i' in the end of new pattern('/pattern/').
4. **ASCII values**: In ereg, if you use number in the pattern, it is
   assumed that you are referring to the ASCII of a character. But in
   preg, number is not treated as ASCII value. So, if your pattern
   contain ASCII value in the ereg expression(for example: new line,
   tabs etc) then convert it to hexadecimal and prefix it with \x.
   `Example: 9(tab) becomes \x9 or alternatively use \t.`

Hope this will help.

Comment: There is a built in for escaping a regex string between delimiters http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 1):

delimiters, add any char to beginning and end of expression, in this case, and by tradition, the '/' character `preg_replace('/.*\.(.*)$/',"\\1",$imgfile);` The regex isn't very good, better to use strrpos and take substr().

Regex is slow, use this.
$extension=substr($imgName,strrpos($imgName,'.'));

Comment: I know but having this problem;

preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '$' in C:\wamp\www..

Comment: Yes, my bad, also the editing seems to destroy the expression. In the end better to use a substr() in this case. You could also use preg_match.

Comment: You can escape your code with backticks (see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  The $ fix looks good.